# Keras program taking too much memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I had been trying to build a network that outputs binary hash of an image.
For this I am using two Vgg-19 network side by side and for training passing two images such that final hash is closer if images are similar and vice-versa. I am using Geforce GTX 1080 with 12 GB of RAM
Here a code snippet to train the model:

```py
#positive images
prim_model.fit(data[index][0], temp_label, epochs=1, verbose=0)
sec_model.fit(data[index][i], temp_label, epochs=1, verbose=0) 
model_vars._calculate_binary([prim_model, sec_model], [index, 0, index, i])

#negative images
prim_model.fit(data[index][0], temp_label, epochs=1, verbose=0)
sec_model.fit(data[index][i], temp_label, epochs=1, verbose=0) 
model_vars._calculate_binary([prim_model, sec_model], [index, 0, index, i])
```

here model_vars is an object holding all important variables of model like

```py
U = a tensor of shape (64, 3200) where 64 is binary bits of output and 3200 is number of images and U represents the output of all the images from prim_model(first model)
V = a tensor of same shape which holds output of sec_model
B = a tensor of shape(16, 3200) storing the final binary values of output
```

now after each fit operation (i.e. images are passed as pairs one to which  we are going to generate hash and other including one similar image and one negative image data[index][0] is target image and in one fit data[index][i] will contain similar image and in another fit it will contain dissimilar image). Here Kbit value is 64
Now after passing a pair I am calculating B tensor using calculate_binary function which is as

```py
for index in xrange(3200):

        Q = some_calculations (a 2-d tenor of shape(16, 3200)


        Q_star_c =  tf.reshape(tf.transpose(Q)[:, (index)], [self.kbit, 1] )    #extracting a column from Q
        U_star_c =  #A column extracted from U
        V_star_c =  #A column extracted from V

        self.U_1 = tf.concat( [ self.U[:, 0:index], self.U[:, index+1: self.total_images]] , axis=1) #Removing the column extracted above from the original now the size of U_1 is (16, 3199)
        self.V_1 = #same as above
        self.B = #slicing the original B tensor


        #Now doing some calcultion to calculate B_star_c (binary value of index'th image
        B_star_c =  tf.scalar_mul(-1, \
                    tf.sign(tf.add(tf.matmul(tf.scalar_mul(2, self.B), \
                    tf.add(tf.matmul(self.U_1, U_star_c, transpose_a=True), tf.matmul(self.V_1, V_star_c, transpose_a=True)) ) , Q_star_c)) )

        #Now combining the final generated binary column to the original Binary tensor making the size of B to be (16, 3200) again
        self.B = tf.concat( [ self.B[:, 0:index], tf.concat( [B_star_c, self.B[:, index:self.total_images]], axis=1)], axis=1)
```

Now after fitting over 100/3200 images my code is running out of memory. It is caused by the calculate_binary function (cause whenever I stop using it the problems solves) When i used htop to review the status of memory its showing complete 32GB/32GB consumption  and even using the swap space. How do I reduce the increasing memory problem.(I had also tried shifting the code to numpy arrays still the same problem is arising)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that it is the tf.concat of self.B...

Because every time the function runs it concatenates self.B bigger and bigger. You can check which tensor is causing the memory error by printing its size on each iteration.